# Definite article in Of-phrases

Tags: definite-article, of-phrases

I wrote:

> A rule is matched based on the properties of the current node and **the current values of context variables**.

**context variables** are specific, then I thought it must be:

> ... **the current values of the context variables**.

But then I though when *values* have a *the*, I might not need to use another "the" for *context variables*.

Is there such a rule?!

What about the first part:

> ... *current values of the context variables*.

does *values* need *the*? why?

Comment: No, there's no such rule. To talk about specific context variables you need the definite article.

Comment: It matters whether they're context variables in general, or specific context variables.  It doesn't really matter whether you used *the* with *values*.  For example, "the weight of cats" = the weight of cats in general.  "The weight of the cats" = the weight of specific cats.

Comment: @stangdon I see, what about the opposite part, I mean the *the* for *values* or *the* of *weight*. why do you use it?

Comment: Apart from ***the** current node*, where the article is required, it's really just a stylistic choice which if any of the other three to include. I think it would be clumsy and verbose to use all four. Personally my preferred option would be *... based on properties of **the** current node and current values of **the** context variables* - but if I were going to include a *third* article it would be the one before ***properties***, not ***current values***.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is less about grammar and more about *style*.  One common rule in good English style is to keep structures parallel when writing lists of things.  For example, "Tomorrow I'm scheduled to *meet* my mother, *visit* the new art exhibit, and *reconsider* my life choices."  All the verbs match tense, and the elements in the list are in the same general sentence structure.

In your example, you have "**the** properties of **the** current node" in the first part of the sentence, so in the second part "**the** current values of **the** context variables" feels more *tidy*.

Alternately you could write, "... the current node's properties and the context variables' current values." It doesn't matter which as long as all of the elements of the list match.